# fopen() URL failure

Tags: php, iis, fopen

I have 2 servers, the main and the test one. They're on the same network.

The users have files in a shared folder, to which both have access, using a virtual directory with read access.

The `PHP.ini` are pretty much the same on core and extensions.

I'm using MPDF to generate a PDF, and in the HTML there is a URL to an image in the shared folder. If I echo the HTML, it shows image, if I do `$mpdf->Output()`; it fails with this `fopen()` error:

> failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection

Both servers have `allow_url_fopen` but only the test server can generate the PDF well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue.  You have 2 users with read access to a virtual directory, and you get an error with $mpdf->Output(); that looks like it may require write access.

Comment: Both servers have same configuration on the virtual directory, and the tests server is successful and the productive isn't

Comment: Does the user running php have access to the folder?

Comment: In a complete desperate move I set in IIS 6.0 permission to Everyone with full control over the virtual directory, and still have the same problem.

Comment: I suppose that depends on your server setup. In a LAMPP setup, it is typically the apache user...

Comment: @gorzan it is fully installed with IIS and as I said, everyone has full control...
in the productive, using:
http:/prod/share/img.jpg fails
http:/tests/share/img.jpg works

Comment: I'm just thinking in terms of multiple security settings.  From the physical location of the files, cascading all the way through the virtual folder, including maybe even share permissions.  Basically if any step in the whole chain doesn't allow the process that will attempt to write to the ultimate destination through, you'll get an error.  As far as what user is concerned, I'm not sure what IIS does for users... Maybe setup a security log to audit failures to access the share to help debug what user is trying and failing.. assuming the request gets that far and isnt being blocked sooner.